# Snap: wrapping auth handler with CSRF checker

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I have the following handler which I use for checking authorization on a given handler:

```
  needsAuth :: Handler App (AuthManager App) () -> Handler App App ()
  needsAuth x = with auth $ requireUser auth noUserHandler x
    where noUserHandler = handleLogin (Just "must be logged in")
```

In `Site.h` I specify a route like so: `("/transfers", needsAuth handleTransfers)` where the signature of handleTransfers is `handleTransfers :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()`.

There are only a few handlers on my app that have user submitted forms; I want to use CSRF checking on them, and I though it would be convenient to wrap the authorized handler with a CSRF checking handler, so I could change the route to something like this:

```
("/test", handleCSRF $ needsAuth handleTest)
```

Based on ideas in the snap-extras package, I've created the function handleCSRF:

```
handleCSRF :: Handler b v () -> Handler b v ()
handleCSRF x = do
  m <- getsRequest rqMethod
  if m /= POST
    then x
    else do tok <- getParam "_csrf"
          s <- gets session
          realTok <- withSession s csrfToken
          if tok == Just (E.encodeUtf8 realTok)
            then x
            else writeText $ "CSRF error"
```

The compilation error is:

```
Couldn't match type `SessionManager' with `AuthManager b'
When using functional dependencies to combine
  MonadState v (Handler b v),
    arising from the dependency `m -> s'
    in the instance declaration in `snap-0.13.2.5:Snap.Snaplet.Internal.Type s'
  MonadState (AuthManager b) (Handler b SessionManager),
    arising from a use of `gets' at src\Site.hs:106:20-23
In a stmt of a 'do' block: s <- gets session
In the expression:
  do { tok <- getParam "_csrf";
       s <- gets session;
       realTok <- withSession s csrfToken;
       if tok == Just (E.encodeUtf8 realTok) then
           x
       else
           writeText $ "CSRF error" }
```

I've tried a number of different variations, but get compilation errors of different varieties... am I heading in the right direction? Is this the correct approach in Snap?

**EDIT**: here is some additional information:

```
data App = App
{ _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App)
, _sess  :: Snaplet SessionManager
, _auth  :: Snaplet (AuthManager App)
, _wmConfig  :: WMConfig
}
makeLenses ''App
```

I'm initializing the session snaplet like so:

```
   s <- nestSnaplet "sess" sess $
       initCookieSessionManager "site_key.txt" "sess" (Just 1200)
```

**EDIT #2/Solution**... @mightybyte gave me the solution via IRC, which was to replace the realTok line with `realTok <- withSession sess (with sess csrfToken)`, which worked.

Thanks in advance,
Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
handleCSRF :: Handler App App () -> Handler App App ()
handleCSRF x = do
  m <- getsRequest rqMethod
  if m /= POST
    then x
    else do tok <- getParam "_csrf"
          realTok <- withSession sess csrfToken
          if tok == Just (E.encodeUtf8 realTok)
            then x
            else writeText $ "CSRF error"
```

The first parameter to [withSession](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.13.2.4/docs/Snap-Snaplet-Session.html#v%3awithSession) should be a lens, not the SessionManager itself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that originally, but am getting errors like 
`Expected type: SnapletLens b SessionManager
 Actual type: AuthManager b0 -> SnapletLens b0 SessionManager 
 In the first argument of 'withSession', namely 'session'
   In a stmt of a 'do' block: realTok <- withSession session`

Comment: I would need to see more information about your app type.  It sounds like you're not actually making any lenses.  Follow the example seen here.  http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/snaplets-tutorial

Comment: Hi @mightybyte, I've added some additional info above on the app type. I also tried changing the line `withSession session` to `withSession sess` and that seemed to get me closer, but started giving me errors like `Expected type: Handler App App T.Text Actual type: Handler App SessionManager T.Text`.

Comment: Yes, `withSession sess` is what it should be.  I've edited my answer above to have that and to make the types more concrete.  I don't have enough information to debug your new error.  I'm pretty sure this should be correct.  I'm guess the problem would be in your csrfToken function.

Comment: feels like we are very close! Down to one remaining error: `Couldn't match type 'SessionManager' with 'App'
  Expected type: Handler App App T.Text
    Actual type: Handler App SessionManager T.Text
  In the second argument of `withSession', namely 'csrfToken'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: realTok <- withSession sess csrfToken`

Comment: Try `s/csrfToken/(withTop' id csrfToken)/` on that withSession line.

Comment: Thanks @mightbyte, you've been very helpful. That's still giving the same error (now with the second argument of withTop'). I'll keep plugging away and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: It would probably be easier to debug this via the #snapframework IRC channel.

Comment: The solution was to replace realTok line with `realTok <- withSession sess (with sess csrfToken)`